# Is it possible to share a Vuex store between a browser app and a Nativescript app via node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nativescript, vuex

For the past week I have been trying to figure out a way to share a vuex store with several modules between a Vue based web app and a Nativescript app. I have been trying to keep the codebases of the two apps separate and instead using a shared module between the two app. I created a module bundled with webpack returned a fairly simple vuex store that mostly handled crud operations between the client and server

However when I tried to get this module to work on Nativescript app it caused the app to crash (with no error messages just dead. The only way I got it to work on the native side was to abandon webpack and point the app towards the unbundled js files. This though caused the module to stop working on the browser side as it was no longer sent through babel to make it browser compatible. I am considering experimenting with browserify, but at this point I feel I am just spinning around in circles.

Has anyone else encountered a problem like this? How would one accomplish code sharing between vue nativescript and vue browser?

Comment: Hi- Welcome to stack overflow. 

Could you edit your question to break it into paragraphs?

Comment: Is that better?